# Splitting program into header and main files

Tags: c++, header

I've been trying to split my program into a header file and the main file but can't quite figure out how exactly a header file would work with this. Any help with trying to understand this would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>


void comparing(std::ifstream& fileIn, std::ifstream& keywords, std::ofstream& outFile)
{
    std::string str;
    std::string word;
    std::set<std::string> keywordsSet;
        int check = 0;

        while (keywords >> word) {
        keywordsSet.insert(word);
        }

    while(fileIn >> str){

        if(str == "<p>") {
            check++;
        }


        if((check > 1 && str == "<p>") || (check == 1 && str == "</body>"))
        {
            outFile << "</p>";
            check--;
        }



    if(keywordsSet.find(str) != keywordsSet.end()) {

        outFile << "<i>" << str << "</i>" << " ";
        }

        else{
        outFile << str << " ";
        }           
    }   

}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

std::ifstream fileIn;
fileIn.open (argv[1]);

std::ifstream keywords;
keywords.open (argv[2]);

std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(argv[3]);

    comparing(fileIn, keywords, outFile);

fileIn.close();
keywords.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should invest in a good c++ book.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you declare one function: `comparing`. You usually put all declarations in a header file (MSVC++ uses the `.h` suffix, but I prefer `.hpp` for C++ headers), and the implementations in a `.cpp` file.

Your header (`comparing.hpp`, or something along those lines) would look like this:

```
// Prevents redefinitions when including the same header multiple times
#pragma once

// Does the same thing, just to make sure 
// (some compilers don't support #pragma once)
#ifndef COMPARING_HPP
#define COMPARING_HPP

#include <fstream>

void comparing(std::ifstream&, std::ifstream&, std::ofstream&); // Function prototype

#endif
```

And your `comparing.cpp` file would look like this:

```
#include "comparing.hpp"
// Note the quotation marks instead of greater than, less than signs
// This is because the header is not in the standard include path,
// but rather in your project include path.

// Implementation, belongs in cpp file
void comparing(std::ifstream& fileIn, std::ifstream& keywords, std::ofstream& outFile)
{
    std::string str;
    std::string word;
    std::set<std::string> keywordsSet;
        int check = 0;

        while (keywords >> word) {
        keywordsSet.insert(word);
        }

    while(fileIn >> str){

        if(str == "<p>") {
            check++;
        }


        if((check > 1 && str == "<p>") || (check == 1 && str == "</body>"))
        {
            outFile << "</p>";
            check--;
        }



    if(keywordsSet.find(str) != keywordsSet.end()) {

        outFile << "<i>" << str << "</i>" << " ";
        }

        else{
        outFile << str << " ";
        }           
    }   

}
```

And then you can use the `compare` function in any `.cpp`, as long as you include the header. So your `main.cpp`* file would look like this:

```
#include "comparing.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

std::ifstream fileIn;
fileIn.open (argv[1]);

std::ifstream keywords;
keywords.open (argv[2]);

std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(argv[3]);

    comparing(fileIn, keywords, outFile);

fileIn.close();
keywords.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

---

** The `main.cpp` file never needs a header; why would you need to call `main` elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You usually place in a header classes and functions declarations and then place in a `.cpp` file the definitions and implementations.